# Invalid Column Name - Declare Variable

Tags: variables, reporting-services

I am using a stored procedure with my SSRS report using @salesperson as a parameter in SSRS. SQL Server Enterprise. Ver 15.0

I am building a temp table in the stored proc, then I use the temp table with the rest of my query. I am trying to run the stored proc in SSMS prior to introducing it to SSRS, but I am getting an INVALID COLUMN error when I run. If I declare @SalesPerson = null it will run, so I believe I am doing something wrong with that line of code.

I want to set my @SalesPerson variable to a few salesperson names for testing, but I can't even get a single salesperson name to work.

EDIT: I can tell my @SalesPerson variable is being declared and SET correctly, so it has to do with how that is interacting with the @InsertSales executible.

Thanks for any help, Brent

```
declare @SalesPerson        varchar (255);
Set @SalesPerson = 'smith';
-- Select @SalesPerson;
         
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#p_traders') IS NOT null DROP TABLE #p_sales

CREATE TABLE #p_sales(lastname varchar(255));

DECLARE @InsertSales varchar(max) = 'insert into #p_sales
  values ('+REPLACE(@SalesPerson,',','),(')+');';
EXEC (@InsertSales);
```

Comment: What database and version is this?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server. SQL Server Enterprise. Ver 15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in string_split function to simplify things

```
DECLARE @SalesPerson as varchar(max) = 'Smith, Jones'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #p_sales

SELECT ltrim(rtrim(value)) as lastname
INTO #p_sales
from string_split(@SalesPerson, ',')

SELECT * FROM #p_sales
```

Gives the following

[image]

Comment: Hi, yes I had it working with the string_split, but I am getting directions to use a temp table as the rest of the stored proc is doing. But, thank you.

Comment: This does use a temp table

Comment: Sorry, just seen that. I copied and ran the code and I am getting invalid object name for string_split

Comment: You are using SQL Sever 2019 yes? It should work fine on that. I just tested this and it worked OK. Can you run the exact bit of code mas in my answer and nake sure that works.

Comment: And check the compatibility level of the database

Comment: Hello,

I did copy the copy directly into the window. I will double-check the version, but I am going to mark it as a solution because it works. Thank you!

Comment: I will do. Thank you!